# Ruby Nokogiri xml parsing

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

Given the following node, I want to search for the value "H90.5" and return the attribute string **dx1**

```
<fld-21 dx-version="ICD10" dx1="H90.5" dx2="I25.9" dx3="I25.3" dx4="" dx5="" dx6="" dx7="" dx8="" dx9="" dx10="" dx11="" dx12=""/>
```

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "I want to search for the value H90.5". Do you want nodes with `dx1="H90.5"` or with any `dx[n]` attribute = H90.5

Comment: The first can be done with [CSS attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Attribute_selectors) but I'm not sure about the later. Could possibly be done with XPath.

Comment: yes, the second...the value I'll search for will only ever exist in the fld-21 node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

```
frag = Nokogiri::XML.fragment('<fld-21 dx-version="ICD10" dx1="H90.5" dx2="I25.9" dx3="I25.3" dx4="" dx5="" dx6="" dx7="" dx8="" dx9="" dx10="" dx11="" dx12=""/>')
```

If you have multiple elements and multiple possible attributes you could do:

```
frag.css('fld-21').map do |node|
  node.attributes.select do |key, attr|
     key =~ /dx\d+/ && attr.value == "H90.5"
  end.keys
end
```

It returns:

```
[["dx1"]]
```

Otherwise you can use `.at` instead of `.css` and `.detect` instead `.select`.

Comment: Additionally `frag.xpath("fld-21/attribute::*").select { |e| e.content == 'H90.5'}.map(&:name)` will return `['dx1']` where `frag.xpath("fld-21/attribute::*")` just returns the attributes

Answer (score 2):

Here's an xpath trick to search attributes:

```
doc.at('//@*[.="H90.5"]').name
```

Comment: Ahhh I was looking for that. Gotta brush up on my XPath game clearly.